# Adding Presign URL Expiration for AWS s3 in aws-sdk-go-v2 for Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go, aws-sdk-go-v2

There is a [very fine example](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/code-examples/s3/generatepresignedurl/) of using the aws-sdk-go-v2 to create pre-signed URLs.

This works well but I'm stuck on setting the expiration time.  I do see the PresignOptions struct has an [`Expires`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/f8d40e3f2986a7e65e515c9c3ae06c07efc7d887/service/s3/api_client.go#L415) but I'm not certain how to do that.

I also see [`WithPresignExpires`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/f8d40e3f2986a7e65e515c9c3ae06c07efc7d887/service/s3/api_client.go#L442) but alas, I also do not know how to use this given the example.

Can an example be provided here?  I'm learning Go but something is just outside my grasp here.

Answer (score 3):

Seems I can do this for 60 minute expiration.

```
func GetPresignedURL(c context.Context, api S3PresignGetObjectAPI, input *s3.GetObjectInput) (*v4.PresignedHTTPRequest, error) {
    return api.PresignGetObject(c, input, s3.WithPresignExpires(3600*time.Second))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass more options to the PresignGetObject function ([aws s3 sdk example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/992358f166e296a68b2c196efe536e72f9bee7e4/gov2/s3/actions/presigner.go#L33))

This example would generate this header `X-Amz-Expires=604800`
which would make the link available for 7 days:

```
request, err := presigner.PresignClient.PresignGetObject(context.TODO(), &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
    Key:    aws.String(objectKey),
}, func(opts *s3.PresignOptions) {
    opts.Expires = time.Duration(7 * 24 * time.Hour)
})
```